# ApachePOI extract digits from RichTextString

Tags: java, replace, apache-poi

I am reading cell values from one Excel sheet and placing them in another with Apache POI. For one particular column I would like to only copy over the numbers of that cell. Naturally I tried this:

```
newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getRichStringCellValue().replaceAll("\\D+",""));
```

I learned that I can't directly use [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) on a [RichTextString](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/RichTextString.html) as it is not of Type `String` which is why I used the method [`getString()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/RichTextString.html#getString--) and tried this:

```
newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().replaceAll("\\D+",""));
```

This worked but by converting it into a `String` I obviously lost all additional information (applied fonts etc.) a RichTextString includes. That is why my question is: **How can I extract only the digits but leave the RichTextString intact?**

Comment: After some quick searching I've found [RichTextStringUtil](http://jett.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/jett/util/RichTextStringUtil.html) class. It got `replaceAll()` method, might be worth checking out. I haven't used it and I don't know what it does.

Comment: I'll look into that Thanks